# Why does LaTeX move my section to a new page?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking

I'm using LaTeX to create a CV, however, parts of my table move to another page.

The following 'experience' bit of the tabular thing goes to a new page. How do I stop this?!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\title{\bfseries\Huge XXXXX}
\author{XXXXX \\ XXXXX}
\date{}

\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\section*{Education}
\begin{tabular}[h]{L!{\VRule}R}
Sept' 2014&{\textbf{School of Hard Knocks}, University of Life}\\[2.5pt]

\end{tabular}


\section*{Experience}
\begin{tabular}{L!{\VRule}R}
July '13--Present&{\bf BlahUnited Kingdom}\\
& \lipsum \\[2.5pt]

\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: as posted your file generates the error: `! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.36 &
`

Comment: If I remove the `{` before the `\bf` on line 36 it runs without error but no section moves to the next page, but it is far to wide because of the `XXXX` Please ensure your example runs without error and demonstrates teh problem that you are asking about.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to an unfixed syntax error in the input

Comment: I'm afraid I had sensitive information that I 'XXXXXX' over. I might have deleted something. Can you spot why a section would be moving over to a new page?

Comment: @H.A. the idea is that the example is an example of the problem, the example as posted just demonstrates several unrelated problems. You need to fix it, or delete it, we don't care about the original text just write hello 50 times if you want, but make the example _an example_

Comment: you have included `lipsum` package: the only use of which is to generate dummy text, you could use it to generate dummy text....

Comment: I've updated it to reflect the problem.

Comment: Hi, Why is this an off-topic conversation? I've created a MWE

Comment: This question should be reopened. Please give the OP a few minutes to fix the question before closing it. To answer the OP's question, the table is pushed to the next page because it won't fit on the first page. Add ``usepackage{longtable}`` to your preamble, and replace ``begin{tabular} ... end{tabular}`` with ``begin{longtable} ... end{longtable}``.

Comment: Two further comments: (1) Much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225). (2) A CV should contain information you can freely distribute. Don't include "sensitive" information in the first place.

Comment: @H.A. Things like typos go down as 'off-topic' as they don't really fit well with the idea of 'generally helpful' question. I see you've now edited the question to deal with that, so it may well get re-opened. What I do notice is that in the current form the stuff you have which appears on page 2 is simply too long to appear on page 1, and as it's in a tabular it can't break across pages. As such, this is 'by design'. I guess we'll need a slightly more realistic example showing roughly the size of your entries.

Comment: @JosephWright My guess is that the OP's example is realistic in the sense that his table was probably too long to fit on the previous page.

Comment: Sverre had it right. Thanks guys, and sorry for making it long winded!

Answer (score 3):

Latex doesn't allow a page break immediately after a section head, it tries to make at least one line of the following paragraph stick to the heading. In your case the only thing on the first line is a table (which counts as a single unit) so latex has to take the section head over to keep it with the table (tabular environments never break)

In this case it seems that really you want a list environment (such as `description`) rather than use `tabular` as list items may break as normal paragraphs.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\title{\bfseries\Huge XXXXX}
\author{XXXXX \\ XXXXX}
\date{}

\usepackage{array, xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.8}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.14\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\newcommand\VRule{\color{lightgray}\vrule width 0.5pt}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\section*{Education}

\begin{description}
\item[Sept 2014]\textbf{School of Hard Knocks}, University of Life
\end{description}

\section*{Experience}
\begin{description}
\item[July 2013--Present]\textbf{BlahUnited Kingdom}

\lipsum 

\end{description}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the missing pair of braces on line 35, this example produces a single page for me.

This really should be a comment, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: If you beef up the 'experience bit' enough, it turns to two pages. Sorry for the mis-haps chaps.